# Does hibernate OGM fully supports IBM Cloudant NoSQL database

Tags: java, hibernate, cloudant, hibernate-ogm

I am wondering if Hibernate OGM is actually compatible with IBM [cloudant](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwik1oeri_zWAhVsCpoKHcE0CGcQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fuk-en%2Fmarketplace%2Fdatabase-management&usg=AOvVaw2r_NLqmo3F7E7i8_TUOI5M) No SQL database?

Have anyone tried this out?

If not, Is there any other OGM which can deal with all the popular NOSQL databases?

Comment: ORM or OGM? They're not the same thing. Which shows the amount of effort you've put into this question.

Comment: OGM, while writing, I might have written ORM, but the question is still the same, documentation doesn't mention cloudant db, so my question is regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently, there is not a dialect for it.

Thanks